# How can I pass a list as a parameter to a dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

Y must pass a list of data to a dialog to fill a combobox. 
In other part of the code I passed a string to dialogs, but, using the same method for this case, It didn´t work.

Here is my js code:

```
$scope.addPartido = function () {
    if ($scope.dataProv.locationsProv.provincias) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '../../secure/addPartido/addPartidoDialog.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.close = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                };
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Inside my controler I have the variable $scope.dataProv.locationsProv.provincias fill with de data.

And here is my html code:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <label>Provincia<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <select ng-options="item.name for item in dataProv.locationsProv.provincias| orderBy:'name'" 
                        ng-id="mySelProvincia" class="form-control" required="required"
                        ng-model="selectedProv">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()">
                Cerrar
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle for your code here? Hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing the format of the other variables you're passing into the `<select>` element.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy!

This code works perfectly:

```
$scope.addPartido = function () {
    if ($scope.dataProv.locationsProv.provincias) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '../../secure/addPartido/addPartidoDialog.html',
            controller: function ($scope, $modalInstance, listProv) {
                $scope.statusProv = 'loading...';
                    $scope.provincia = "Select provincias";
                    $scope.dataProv = {
                        "locationsProv": {}
                    };

                    $scope.dataProv.locationsProv.provincias = listProv;
                $scope.close = function () {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                };
            }, 
            resolve: {
                    listProv: function () {
                        return $scope.dataProv.locationsProv.provincias;
                    }
                }
        });
    }
};
```